# Changing styles of TOC of Bookdown, Gitbook style

Tags: css, bookdown, tableofcontents, gitbook

I like to tweak the styles (e.g. background-color, font) of the TOC of the **Bookdown**, **Gitbook style** HTML document. 
Is this possible? If so, can someone be kind enough to point me to where I can start to do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Two steps:

1) Use a custom `style.css` file. 
2) Reference `style.css` in the `_output.yml` file.

The TOC has the `li` class. Your `style.css` file looks like this if you want to have all TOC items in blood:

style.css

```
li {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

_output.yml

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  css: style.css
```

There are other styles that can be modified. For example:

[R Bookdown - Customize width of TOC/Sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805885/r-bookdown-customize-width-of-toc-sidebar)