# R Bookdown - Customize width of TOC/Sidebar

Tags: css, r, bookdown, gitbook

Although I can change the width and position of different elements in the body of an r bookdown doc by modifying the page wrapper in the .css, is there a way to change the width of the sidebar by modifying the styles sheet?

I'm not looking to change the font or color of the words in the TOC, just the width. Something like:

width: 50px;
margin-right: 0;

I don't need a wide sidebar, but I do need more width in the body.

I already widened the inner body as much as possible, so all that is left is the sidebar.

Answer (score 5):

In your `_output.yml` add the css filename

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  css: style.css
```

Create `style.css` to change the default 300px

```
.book .book-summary {
  width: 350px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-350px;
}

.book.with-summary .book-header.fixed {
    left: 350px;
}

.book.with-summary .book-body {
    left: 350px;
}
```

Comment: It works whenever the sidebar is visible. But when I click on the toggle sidebar button to make disappear the menu, the sidebar does not close completely. 50px remain left from the sidebar.